# Not allow specific words to be typed in input tag html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, input

I have a simple input tag in html where users type their names.
How can i make that input not to accept specific words? I am not fan of regex
and i will prefer something more readable if it is possible. Simple javascript or jquery are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `indexOf`, but that probably leads to false positives.

Comment: Not being a fan of a tool doesn't make it not the right one ;)

Comment: Regex is readable if you know regexes. Same goes for anything else.

Comment: @Joel I said "if it is possible"!!. Look at xbonez example.

Comment: only because you are not able to do it, doesn't mean its not the right toool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using javascript's `string.indexOf` function.

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/JVrHq/2/

You can extend on this by having an array of disallowed words.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it without Regex in JavaScript.

But in code behind you can use  **Contains("badword")** method of any string variable. (It is for .NET)